# Tween a node's rotation from nearest direction

Tags: c#, godot, godot4

I'm spining an entity through the `Tween` type:

```cs
if (this._direction != AutomobileDirection.Up)
{
    if (this._rotationTweenIsActive())
    {
        this._stopRotationTween();
    }
    this._direction = AutomobileDirection.Up;
    this._initRotationTween();
    this._rotationTween.TweenProperty(this._collision, "rotation_degrees", 180, 0.3);
}
```

I'm having a problem with `this._rotationTween.TweenProperty`. For example, if `this._collision.Rotation` equals `-45`, it goes to `180` through the worst direction. Is there a way to tween to the nearest direction?